# multi-dimensioned array initialization using const

Tags: c

This kind of initialization works

```
int arr[3][4] = { {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3,4}, {1,2,3,4} } ;
```

but this one here doesn't

```
const size_t row_size = 3;  
const size_t col_size = 4;  

int arr[row_size][col_size] = { {1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4},{1,2,3,4}};
```

these codes are in c but after changing the file extension to c++ and re-compiling
it works fine. why such a behavior?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: [**Cannot reproduce**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c3eb298aca4bb95b)

Comment: @JosephMansfield "variable sized object may not be initialized"

Comment: Which compiler do you use?

Comment: I get that error if I compile as C, not C++, using GCC. Make sure you're using a C++ compiler, or if it is C, retag the question and accept that you can't use a `const` variable as a constant expression.

Comment: @leemes GNU GCC compiler.

Comment: "why such a behavior?" Because C and C++ are different languages (specifically, they have different ideas about whether array sizes must be constant, and which type of expressions count as constants). Don't expect arbitrary code from one to work in the other; choose one language and stick to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That used to be a problem with C and macros were used to solve such problems. But in C++ if you use "const" keyword then the compiler should automatically replace those values during compile time so there shouldn't be any problem with g++. That code runs perfectly fine when compiled with g++. Maybe you are trying to compile it with gcc (I got the same error with gcc which is as expected).

Answer (score 0):

Actually, having a `const`-variable doesn't mean it is constant at compile time. For example, I can

```
void f(int x) {
    const int y = x;
    int m[y]; // should that work?
}
```

It won't work in good old C++03, as compiler cannot determine `y` at compile time. Though it would be possible in C++ soon with the feature called [Variable Length Arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array), it seems all you want is plain compile-time constant. Just say it's also `static`:

```
static const int size_t row_size = 3;
```

Since now, you can use it in compile-time.

Comment: True, but `const size_t n = 42;` *is* a compile time constant.

Comment: @juanchopanza Shouldn't that be `constexpr` then?

Comment: @juanchopanza I don't remember anything like that in C++ standard. Probably, I should take another look there.

Comment: I think C only cares about whether or not the array size is a _constant expression_, which is not necessarily the same thing as compile-time constant. I'm not certain about the details so I'll refrain from posting an answer of my own.